# I dont understand the differences between using push vs using unshift in my code

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm supposed to create a function named reversePlusOne. This function should:

Take one argument, an array of at least two numbers.
This function should return:
the array reversed with a 1 added at the front. 
when i used push(1) works but when i use unshift it doesn't. Can someone explain

```
return a.push(1), a.reverse();
return a.reverse(), a.unshift(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

`reverse` returns the array. `unshift` returns the new length, read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift). Therefore

```
return a.push(1), a.reverse();
return a.reverse(), a.unshift(1), a;
```

Answer (score 1):

push adds to the end of an array, unshift adds to the beginning

```
var arr = [8,5];
// this creates an array with 8 and 5 
arr.reverse()
// this reverses the array
arr.unshift(1);
// this adds to the beginning of the array.
arr.push(1);
// this adds to the end of the array.
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/50s8xvqx/1/

Comment: And this explains the OP's question, which is that his two alternatives don't return the same result, how?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, here is an example.

Reverse

```
arr = [0,1,2,3];

arr.reverse();

arr is now equal to [3,2,1,0], it has been reversed
```

Push

```
arr = [0,1,2,3];

arr.push(1);

arr is now equal to [1,0,1,2,3], note that we pushed the 1 on to the end
```

Unshift

```
arr = [0,1,2,3];

arr.unshift(1);

arr is now equal to [1,0,1,2,3], note that we added the 1 to the 0 index
```

Push and reverse

```
arr = [0,1,2,3];

arr.push(1);

arr.reverse();

arr is now equal to [1,3,2,1,0], we pushed a value to the end and then reversed the order
```

Unshift and reverse

```
arr = [0,1,2,3];

arr.unshift(1);

arr.reverse();

arr is now equal to [3,2,1,0,1], we pushed a 1 to the 0 index and reversed
```

After reviewing these examples, you should see the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the operations, but their return values.

```
return a.push(1), a.reverse();
```

First, the comma operator returns its second argument, but it's a bit misleading to take advantage of that.  This would be clearer if it were written like this:

```
a.push(1);
return a.reverse();
```

Now, `reverse` modifies the array in place, but it also returns the array (with its new value), so this yields the correct result.  Whereas your second version:

```
return a.reverse(), a.unshift(1);
```

Is the same as this:

```
a.reverse();
return a.unshift(1);
```

So you are modifying the array to the correct value, but what you're returning is not that array. Instead, you're returning the return value of `unshift`, which, like `push`, returns the new length of the array, not the array itself.

The two versions below are equivalent:

```
a.push(1);
a.reverse();
return a;
```

and

```
a.reverse();
a.unshift(1);
return a;
```

Comment: The correct term for the comma operator is "operand", not "argument".

Answer (score 0):

The return statement with multiple comma seperated expressions runs those expressions and then returns the result of the last one of them,

For example let say you've this return statement

`return 1+1,5,7+78;`

the returned value in this case is `85` which is the evaluation of the last expression.

To come back to your question, as @torazaburo said:

- The **[unshift()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)** method adds new items to the beginning of an array, and **returns the new length**.
- The **[reverse()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp)** method **reverses** the order of the elements in an array and **returns the reversed array**.

So,

```
return a.push(1), a.reverse();
```

returns the last expression value which is **a.reverse()**

and

```
return a.reverse(), a.unshift(1);
```

returns what the last expression return, it means the **a.unshift(1)** return value.

Comment: To be pedantic, it is not that "the `return` statement 'runs' the comma separated expressions". It is that the comma operator *evaluates* each of its *operands* and returns the last one as the value of the operator, and returns simply returns the result of the comma operator as it does any other expression it might be given.